# Flash Messages with CI_Sessions

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am having trouble with Flash Messages when `$config['sess_use_database']` is `TRUE`. Whenever, it is `FALSE` it works without any problems. Below is my code and my configuration file. Why does it not work when I try to store the sessions in the database?

**Configuration File**

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 7200;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 300;
```

**Controller**

```
 $this->session->set_flashdata('item', array('message' => 'Record created successfully','class' => 'success'));
 redirect('dashboard');
```

**Dashboard View**

```
if(!empty($this->session->flashdata('item'))) {
  $message = $this->session->flashdata('item');
  echo "<div class='" . $message['class'] . ">" . $message['message'] . "</div>";
}
```

Comment: I suppose you have created the table **ci_sessions** in your database?